# Eclipse workspace folder seems empty?

Tags: android, eclipse, workspace

I created a new workspace and imported my projects from another workspace to the new one.I can see the projects inside eclipse but the new workspace folder seems empty in windows explorer.I want to commit my code to github.But can't do it because of this.How to resolve this ?

Comment: Hey actually you accessed that workspace project only thats the reason you didnt have that project in your current workspace so just copy and past ur current workspace. i think your project present in this location Git->project and then followed by your folder.

Comment: Try to select the copy projects to workspace checkbox while importing the projects...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default while importing any project in eclipse will be refereed from its original location only. So Make sure whenever you import any project from anywhere in your workspace you copy that project into your workspace also. Otherwise it will refer the original location of the project.

Just you need to check the highlighted checkbox while importing a project as shown in image.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

when you imported project did you selected option to copy those projects to new workspace.

when you don't select that option that project is not copied to new workspace and eclipse only make reference to existing directory.

You can copy those projects to new workspace and then Import it.

Answer (score 1):

copy that project folder inside your new workspace then give it to the building path from eclipse then commit to the  github from your new workspace